# We call the shots as we see them

Tags: syntax, grammar, modification

I was invited to ask here.

I sometimes hear the sentence "we call the shots as we see them." I want to ask whether the as-clause modifies "shots" (just like "as we know it" modifies "life" in "Life as we know it will cease to exist") or "call.”

The reason I am asking this question is that as for the similar idiomatic pharse "call it as I see it," the as-clause "as I see it" seems to me not to modify "it" if the same rule as appleied in the use of the relative "that" (e.g., the relative clause "that we bought at the store" cannot modify the preceding noun if it is pronoun as in *we sold it that we bought at the store) holds of this case. Then, the only option seems to be treat the as-clause as a adverbial modifier modifying the verb or verbal phrase including "call," I guess. And if it is possible, I wonder whether and why "as we see them" in "we call the shots as we see them." modifies "call". But nevertheless it does not seem to me that the as-clause indeed does it.

The reason for this is that the manner of one's calling something and that of one's seeing something are related to different sensory organs and therefore imcompatible with each other.

I also suspect that this as-clause actually functions as predicate complement of the obeject (i.e., shots) just like the as-clause "as you find it" in "Leave everything as you find it" does.

But I'm not sure.

So, please tell me about "we call the shots as we see them" and "call it as I see it."

The relevant examples are below:

1.Steve, we're simply telling examiners that you have to do your job in a professional manner, call the shots as you see them and....

2.M-O'BRIEN: Nothing gets an A. To the extent that this feeds into a perception that Democrats are maybe whining about all of this, how do you respond to that? SCHUMER: OK. First, you've got to call the shots as you see them.

And I found the relevant question at https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/we-call-the-shots-as-we-see-them.1394794/

Comment: sorry, at present I cannot post another  relevant question that I should have posted first and that is more basic. So it would be greatly appreciarted if you read this question, you also go to another question, which will be posted in 30 minutes later or so.

Comment: I could post it. Here is a link:https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45930/about-shes-going-to-tell-the-truth-as-she-saw-understood-it-and-he-then-descr

Comment: Why would you expect _as_ to function the same way as the relative subordinator _that_? They’re entirely different entities. Intuitively, I think of the _as_ clause as modifying the verbal phrase rather than the noun phrase, but I cannot off the top of my head think of a definite reason why this must be so.

Comment: (Why would you expect as to function the same way as the relative subordinator that? They’re entirely different entities)→Because "as we know it" in "Life as we know it"  modfifies "Life" just like "that we know" in "the life/world that we know" modifies "life/world." How do think about it?

Comment: Well, they’re similar semantically. That doesn’t mean they work the same syntactically – in fact, we can clearly see that they don’t, since in the relative clause a resumptive pronoun is forbidden (the life that we know \*it), whereas in the _as_ clause it’s required (life as we know \*∅).

Comment: Yes, these syntactic behaviors are right, but nevertheless it is true that the as-caluse and the that-clause MODIFY the preceding noun, right ?

Comment: That doesn’t mean it does in ‘call X as I see it/them’. If we separate out the verb and the noun by turning the phrase into a question/answer pair, semantics dictate that the _as_ clause modifies the noun in one and the verb in the other: “We are bound to life as we know it” can become “What life are we bound to? – Life as we know it”, but not “*How are we bound to life? – As we know it”; conversely, “I call the shots as I see them” can become “How do I call the shots? – As I see them”, but not “*What shots do I call? – The shots as I see them”.

Comment: yes, yes, I agree with you.  You misunderstand what I want to ask. I don't say that these two types of as-clauses must  modify the preceding noun.  My way of thinking is as follows: in "She is going to tell the truth as she saw it" the as-clause modifies "truth," not "tell," right. If "as I see them" modifies "call" in "I call the shots as I see them," why the as-caluse "as she saw it" does not or cannot modify "tell" ?

Comment: It is a complicated matter, but ,say, in "you must do as I did," the as-clause modifies "do," which means that the as-clause depicts manner (i.e., how to do). This sentence is straightforward and easy to understand since how you do and how I did are compatible with each other because the the type of action is the same. That's why the as-clause can function as a verbal modifier.

Comment: BUT how to tell and how to see, and how to call and how to see are incompatible with each other because of different sensory  organs being used to act these actions.  So, "as I see them" functions not as a verbal modifier, but as the predicate complement of "shots" just like  the as-clause "as you find it" in "Leave everything as you find it"  and "dishonest in "I called him dishonest" functions as the predicative complement of "shots" and "him," respectively.  These are my way of reasoning and the reason for why I don't technically feel "as I seem them" modifies "tell."  Make sense?

Comment: I don’t see why different sensory organs should make a difference semantically (or syntactically). _Tell/call_ and _see_ are perfectly compatible to me; “I tell it as I hear it” works fine too as verb-modifying. However, in “She’s going to tell the truth as the saw it”, I’d say it **is** ambiguous what the _as_ clause relates to: is she going to tell the truth in the same manner that she saw it, or is she going to tell her perception of the truth? In this particular case, both are equally possible and likely.

Comment: Thank you.

(I don’t see why different sensory organs should make a difference semantically (or syntactically). Tell/call and see are perfectly compatible to me) → Because we cannot say e.g.,  "I will tell a story in the way I eat." In this case, how to eat is irrelevant to how to tell, right? I and my informants of native English speakers think that the same reasoning can hold in the relationship between how to tell/speak and how to see/undrstand. Do you agree or disagree with these points? Could you tell me how these points are accounted for.

Comment: (supplemental information: one of my informants says that how she saw it does not really describe how she talked; how does one talk in a way they see?)

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to use _eat_ because eating and telling a story have nothing to do with each other, not because they’re different sensory inputs. You don’t eat stories. _See_ (in a broader sense of ‘perceive’ or ‘take in’, or in the sense ‘consider’) makes sense with anything you can perceive audiovisually or have an opinion about.

Comment: I just showed you an extreme case where the manner interpretation is weird. Then, How about "get" or "write"?  Although we can get or write a story, "tell a story as I get it/I write it" does not seem to be related to the manner interpretation, right? 
I understnad what you said about "see," though.

Comment: The preposition phrase "as we see them" is a modifier (adjunct) in clause structure, i.e. in the VP "call the shots". Its semantic type is 'manner'.

Comment: BillJ, thank you.

Comment: I found a interesting example " Give us the details as you have them. MATT-ZAPOTOSKY-REPO: Yes." In this case, is the manner interpretation weird, right?